# MSAL token expires after 1 hour

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL for Azure AD authentication in a Xamarin app. The validity of the token is 1 day (seen using the value of **ExpiresOn** of AuthenticationResult). 
My problem is that, after 1 hour, AcquireTokenSilentAsync fails and then AcquireToken needs to be called.

I am not able to understand that even though the token validity is 1 day, and the validity of refresh token is even more, why is it asking for authentication after every 1 hour ? 
Can this be changed using any parameter value or any other way ?

Comment: You are going to need to show some of the code where you do the authentication and try to use the token.

Answer (score 15):

Just to make a small clarification, MSAL doesn't actually issue tokens or decide a token expiration, but rather ingests an acquires token from the Azure AD STS.

MSAL will automatically refresh your access token after expiration when calling AcquireTokenSilentAsync.  You're likely not getting automatic silent refreshes due to some kind of token cache miss.  It's hard to say the specific issue without seeing your code, but i'll recommend comparing it against the [official MSAL Xamarin code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2).

If you're building a Xamarin app, then it's a public client. The default token expirations right now are:

***Access Tokens:*** 1 hour

***Refresh Tokens:*** 90 days, 14 day inactive sliding window

Azure AD does allow you to configure these token expirations in PowerShell.  You can define a *token lifetime policy* and then assign it to the specific Service Principal, across the tenant/organization, or on the application object.  The other thing to keep in mind is if you're requesting a token for a specific resource, then the policy must be set on that resource rather than the requesting service principal or app. For more info on this, checkout [configuring token lifetime in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the TokenCache due to which token was not stored properly and I was getting an exception. This has been resolved in the newer versions of Xamarin Android. Bug defined [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37491)